# Entity framework: detaching but keeping object graph

Tags: entity-framework, dispose, detach

I'm working in a disconnected scenario, but I noticed that disposing an object context does not release attached entities. As a result, subsequent operations often fail because of this.

So to solve this, I detach everything myself when the object context is being disposed:

```
public void Dispose()
{
   // detaching is not really needed, because we have short living object contexts
   var objectStateEntries = 
       _context.UnderlyingContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Unchanged);           
   objectStateEntries.ToList().ForEach(o => { if (o.Entity != null)
   {                
     _context.UnderlyingContext.Detach(o.Entity);               
   }});            

   _context.Dispose();
   _context = null;    
}
```

However, the side effect is that the object graph gets detached completely, but I really want to keep the graph!

It seems I don't find a solution for this, is it true that it can't be done?

Comment: Can you explain the problem better, it seems to me none of this should be necessary. How do the 'not released' entities cause problems?

Comment: Well, assume that I create a complex entity in a disconnected client, send it to the back-end that creates this entity using entity framework. This works, and the updated entity is sent back to the disconnected client. Then the client updates the entity, changing some properties, maybe adding and removing entities to collections. Back on the back-end, I then re-attach what is needed, but I often get the error that the entity is already attached. But if I try to check this using TryGetObjectStateEntry, it also throws an exception telling me that it's not in the context! (tbc)

Comment: So it seems that there is a conflict because I try to use an entity that is still attached to a previous object context. If I first detach this entity when the first context gets disposed, I don't have any problems. Therefore I conclude that an entity should always be detached if it's going to be used in another context. True?

Comment: I used this code to fix a memory leak.  The Entity Framework Entity Context does clear it's internal cache on dispose. If the graph of entities in the context is large enough the Garbage Collector may not collect the memory resulting in a memory leak.  Detaching/Decoupling the cached entities on dispose of the context fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this problem as well; you cannot have part of a graph attached to an EF context. Have you considered loading up data initially in a detatched state? The context is then used as a stateless repository of data and nothing else.

You can load up data as detatched initially as follows:

```
myDataContext.MyEntitySet.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
```